# what to do in 2016 with fine working HTC Desire hardware from 2010?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, htc

I use since 6 years a [HTC Desire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Desire). I love that phone and it works great.

> The HTC Desire (codenamed Bravo)[4] is the first smartphone of the
>   Desire series developed by HTC. It was announced on 16 February 2010
>   and released in Europe and Australia in the second quarter of the same
>   year. The HTC Desire was HTC's third flagship phone running
>   Android,[5] 2.1 Eclair which can be upgraded to 2.2 Froyo or 2.3
>   Gingerbread.[6] Internally it bears a strong resemblance to the Nexus
>   One, but differs in some features.

I run Android 2.2. I tried the 2.3 upgrade, but it was terrible. I was forced to downgrade.

> system    Launched with Android 2.1 Eclair Upgradeable to Android 2.3
>   Gingerbread[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Desire) (Though only 2.2 is supported by HTC)

WhatsApp announced that they will discontinue Android 2.2 support end of 2016: [So, by the end of 2016, we will be ending support for WhatsApp Messenger on the following mobile platforms:](https://blog.whatsapp.com/10000617/WhatsApp-support-for-mobile-devices)

It's my top used App.

So now my question: what to do in 2016 with a fine working HTC Desire from 2010? I don't wish to buy a new phone, but I wish to use WhatsApp.

I don't wish to install experimental software. At the moment the phone runs 99.99% stable.

Answer (score 1):

Try a Cyanogen Mod version for it..

I used HTC Dev site to unlock the boot loader, And then installed CWM Recovery and flashed several custom ROMs, Wich all seem to be based off of CM9 etc....